# Pre-defined Value setting to Radio Button in recursive loop Failed in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to prepare an online question paper editor and came across an issue related to setting radio button values when populating existing questionnaire details to the form.

This is the JSON response format which used to populate the form. I am using nested `ng-repeat` in order to do the processing and that worked well. The only problem causing element is the radio option where the correct answer selected.

```
 "questions": [
    {
      "question_num": "Q1",
      "answersList": [
        {
          "is_correct": "0",
          "answer_text": "Answer 1",
          "feedback": "Feedback 1"
        },
        {
          "is_correct": "0",
          "answer_text": "Answer 2",
          "feedback": "Feedback 2"
        },
        {
          "is_correct": "0",
          "answer_text": "Answer 3",
          "feedback": "Feedback 3"
        },
        {
          "is_correct": "1",
          "answer_text": "Answer 4",
          "feedback": "Feedback 4"
        }
      ],
      "question_text": "Sample Question"
    }
 ]
```

This is the HTML view details.

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in question.answersList track by $index">
    <input type="radio" value="{{answer.is_correct}}" ng-model="answer.is_correct" name="$index">
    <input type="text" class="desc-text" value="{{answer.answer_text}}" ng-model="answer.answer_text">
    <input type="text" class="desc-text" value="{{answer.feedback}}" ng-model="answer.feedback">
</div>
```

In the prospective solution, the radio button should be checked when `is_correct = 1`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: one possible way, to 'check' a radio button, may be when: `ng-value=true`, do you think it can work for you app?

Comment: No, it didn't help. The problem is since there are multiple questions, I cannot select  the correct answer at each question independently. Instead, the current behaviour allows to select only one record for the whole question sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by doing the following change to the code.

```
<input type="radio" name="{{$parent.$index}}" ng-value="1" ng-model="answer.is_correct">
```

Since the radio options should be grouped for each answer in the answer list, we may need to sub group them based on the question index. Hence had to use `name="{{$parent.$index}}"`.

In order to pre-select the correct answer for the question, used `ng-value="1"` as my data set returns 1 and 0 as values. This can be set to true/false, etc.

In order to manage the two way data binding with the selected input the data model changed as `ng-model="answer.is_correct"`. This will carry forward the existing selection if no changes or new selection itf it got changed in this instance.

Hope this will help someone in the future to overcome such situations.